# select control option variable replace in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I replace the string in the following select  tag with a variable in javascript.
This is what I have.

```
<select id="requestItemStatus" name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-custom" data-native-menu="false">
    <option value="Open">Open</option>                                      
</select>

javascript

'<option value='G_requestsStatus_returnset[0].ItemRequestedStatusID'>'G_requestsStatus_returnset[0].Name'</option>'
```

Comment: which string do you mean?

Comment: Why does your SELECT tag have two ID attributes? What string do you want to replace?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You need to tell us what you expect to be the result given the above input.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean something like this?

```
<select id="requestItemStatus" name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-custom" data-native-menu="false">
    <option id="foo" value="Open">Open</option>                                      
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("foo").text = "Close";

</script>
```

This will change your option to 'close' or whatever is in the "", so all you have to do now is insert that line where you want it to be called